# Switch Statement on didSelectRowAt Function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am using a **table view** and has a *label* in its cell. The thing I want is to change the cell label on every tap of a cell. I know that **switch** statement doesn't work on *indexPath*. I want my cases 1 and 2 to work.

Here is my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 
  let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

 switch Value {
            
        case 1:
            
            cell.cellLabel.text = "first time label changes"
        case 2:
            
            cell.cellLabel.text = "second time label changes"
            
        default:
            cell.cellLabel.text = "change the label"
        }

}
```

Does anyone have a solution that if I tap a cell first time case 1 should work and if I tap it again case 2 should work?

Comment: Basically it's a bad idea to modify the cells outside of `cellForRow` because the changes are not persistent.

Comment: To clear this one thing up: You're misunderstanding what the `indexPath` is. Its the position of the cell in the list and has nothing to do with interaction, so naturally it does not change if you select the cell. 
In a TableView, the IndexPath consists of `row` and `section` to group your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try my code

```
var count = 0
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
count += 1
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
switch count {   
    case 1:
        cell.cellLabel.text = "first time label changes"
    case 2:
        cell.cellLabel.text = "second time label changes"
        
    default:
        cell.cellLabel.text = "change the label"
    }
}
```

if you need "first" when you touch it 3 times

```
 var count = 0
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   count += 1
   if count > 2 {
    count = 1
   }
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
   switch count {   
   case 1:
     cell.cellLabel.text = "first time label changes"
   case 2:
     cell.cellLabel.text = "second time label changes"
   default:
     cell.cellLabel.text = "change the label"
  }
}
```

Comment: I made count 0 on case 2. So, when case 2 works the count becomes 0.

Comment: @TaimoorArif yes, good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedRows = [Int]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
       
            selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)
            print(selectedRows)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       
            if let index = selectedRows.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
                selectedRows.remove(at: index)
            }
            print(selectedRows)
           self.tableView.reloadData()
            if selectedRows.isEmpty{
               
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
            if (selected) {
                print("selected")
                
                selectImage.image = UIImage(named:"secondImage")
              } else {
                  selectImage.image = UIImage(named:"secondImage")
              }
        }
}
```

if you need multiple selection write `tableView.allowMultipleSelection = true`